# Aligning tableLayout Container center horizontally

Tags: codenameone

I've a tableLayout(2 column) in a container with widthPercentage 30 and 50 ie total 80%. But I am having difficult time to keep the tableContainer in the center horizontally. If I use the bgColor, the tableContainer seems to take all of the screenWidth.

```
public MyBooking(Resources res) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainContainer);

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(5, 2);
    Container tableContainer = new Container(tl);

    tableContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), dateLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), dateData)
                                .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), timeLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), timeData)
                                .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), stationLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), stationData)
                                .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), advisorLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), advisorData)
                                .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), problemsLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), problemContainer)
                                .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(30), remarksLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), remarksData);

    mainContainer.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(tableContainer));
    revalidate();
}
```

[image]

Using bgcolor:

```
tableContainer.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
tableContainer.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
```

[image]

Using "mainContainer.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(tableContainer))" have no effect in the layout. Why is that?

Comment: I posted an answer of "why this is happening?". I didn't post an answer on how to accomplish what you are trying to achieve since it wasn't clear. If you just want a blank 20% just add another column but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: I have used table layout with 2 columns (30 & 50 widthPercentage ie. 80%). Hence I wonder why the container using tableLayout with 80 width percentage is taking whole screen? P..S I've used bgColor to determine the width that the tablelayout container has taken. (see the colored img)

Answer (score 0):

That's why we don't recommend using that flow layout trick for anything other than really simple deterministic components.

When you only give out 80% that impacts the preferred width but a layout doesn't have to care about that. Since the component involved is really large and has undetermined size `FlowLayout` tries to reflow and fails badly (it essentially tries to "break a line"). Since it goes to the new line the first line (where your table is) takes the entire "row".